Theme is not applying to the menu buttons on start
The menu theme is not applying to the buttons on start. Once you play through the quiz once and go back to the menu, the menu's theme then applies to the buttons
def menu():
    def start_game():
        menu.destroy()
        quiz_main()
        
    def exit_game():
        menu.destroy()

    menu = tk.Tk()
    menu.title('Menu')
    menu.geometry('600x500')
    
    style = ThemedStyle(menu)
    style.theme_use("black")
    
    style.configure("Tbutton", font=("Helvetica", 20))
    style.configure("Exit", font=("Helvetica", 16))

    start_button = ttk.Button(
        menu,
        text="Start",
        command=start_game,
        state="Enabled"
    )
    start_button.pack(pady=40)
    
    start_button = ttk.Button(
        menu,
        text="Exit",
        command=exit_game,
        state="Enabled", 
    )
    start_button.pack(pady=40)
    
    menu.mainloop()

menu()

I have tried to set a theme inside of the button code to no avail and I have also tried switching the location of the menu theme itself to no avail


Your outer function name is "menu" and inside also you are using an object named "menu", I think that might be a case.
Why are you doing menu.destroy() at the start of the game?

